# Relax NG parser error

Tags: xml, parsing, relaxng

I am tring to validate my `.xml` against `.rng` but I keep getting this error

```
 parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xEA 0x63 0x68 0xE9
            <name>Ev▒ch▒ of Seeet Di▒</name>   //here the original word is Evéchç of seeet diè
                    ^
myfile.xml:33: parser error :      Entity 'nbsp' not defined
            <name>SCIEF&nbsp; Toto</name>
```

in my rng file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The byte sequence `0xEA 0x63 0x68 0xE9` is "`êché`" in ISO-8859-1 (and other charsets), so it seems the first word in the part of the source cited there is actually "`Evêché`"? (not "`Evéchç`"…)

In UTF-8 the bytes for `êché` would be `0xC3 0xAA 0x63 0x68 0xC3 0xA9`.

So it seems the source isn’t actually encoded in UTF-8 but instead in ISO-8859-1 or something?

If so the XML declaration must be changed to `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` or the source needs to converted to UTF-8 (e.g., using [`iconv`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv)).

As far as the error about `&nbsp;`, that’s because it’s an HTML character reference and not defined for arbitrary XML documents. Just replace it with `&#160;` or `&#xA0;`and that error will go away.